# Read from character delimted file and assign into variables | for email

Tags: files, ksh, variable, read

I am using ksh.

I need to read the data from file, into the variables and then further use them for sending emails.

- File can be delimited by any less used characters (like | ^ etc.) or group of characters.
- Need to retrieve **mail from, mail to,cc,bcc, subject, body** from file.
- File is having only one record.
- I am spooling into file from table, thus delimiter can be any character, but less used in general english because characters like , & * etc. might be present in Body and that may return wrong value.

**File:** (***cc*** and **bcc** are not available in the file i.e they are blank)

```
na734@company.com|NA734@company.COM|||TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR|Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>

Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>
The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.
Regards,<br>
FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>

This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail
Reply to the following person for further details:
na734@company.com
```

**Code using:**

```
while IFS='|' read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
do 
flag1=`echo $a1`
flag2=`echo $a2`
flag3=`echo $a3`
flag4=`echo $a4`
flag5=`echo $a5`
flag6=`echo $a6`
done < $RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System`date +%y%m%d`.csv
```

**It is not setting the variables.**

And when using code below: It is showing undesired output:

```
while IFS='|' read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
do 
echo $a1
echo $a2
echo $a3
echo $a4
echo $a5
echo $a6
done < $RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System`date +%y%m%d`.csv
```

**Output:** (**Hell lot of blank lines**)

```
na734@company.com
NA734@company.COM


TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR
Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>






Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>





The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.





Regards,<br>





FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>











This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail





Reply to the following person for further details:





na734@company.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have all fields in first row of file you can use the following code:

```
IFS='|' read -d ^ -a field < "$RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System`date +%y%m%d`.csv"
```

Please note that `^` can be any symbol which surely should not meet in the text to operate it trough till the end.

All necesary fields will be stored into array **field**  starting from 0-element: *field[0]* , *field[1]* ... *field[5]* and can be checked by

```
unset i
for element in 'mail from' 'mail to' cc bcc subject body
do
  echo "$element : ${field[i++]}"
done
```

Comment: It's throwing `bad read option`. I request pardon, but I'm new to shell and thus not able to debug much of the things by myself. Error is `mail_error_file.ksh[158]: read: bad option(s)
usage: tail [+/-[n][lbc][f]] [file]
       tail [+/-[n][l][r|f]] [file] `

Comment: @Sachin May there are some difference between `bash` and `ksh`. To settle issue you should check `man tail` for right option. It can be `--lines=+2` or `+n 2` (the main goal output all file but without 1st line)

Comment: Nah, it's not working. I turned out to solve it by spooling BODY (which have multiple lines in itself) in different file and all other fields in other file. And then using them separately.

Comment: Try to use `tail` with different options. If success put it in variable `var=$(tail +n 2 file)` than `field[5]=$(echo -e "${field[5]}\n$var")`

Comment: @Sachin Edited and much simplified.